# Google Sheets: Update Every Second - =NOW() Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have a `=NOW()` function, but in the settings, the only way for this to update is either on edit, or every minute. Is there a way for this to update every second? I have previously tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316079/when-text-is-full-create-new-row-and-repeat).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When text is full, create new row and repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316079/when-text-is-full-create-new-row-and-repeat)

Comment: This is what I previously posted

Comment: No. it is not possible.  People who need this are often trying to do some sort of scraping.  Is that the case for you?

Comment: @MattKing yes, as [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316079/when-text-is-full-create-new-row-and-repeat) was a failed attempt to get a never-ending code.

Comment: what is the website you are trying to scrape from?

Comment: @MattKing I was using Google Apps Script, as you can see in the question above.

Comment: when i click the link it says "page not found"

Comment: @MattKing it was deleted, but I have edited and requested for an undelete :(